# jQuery DataTables fixed size for ONE of the columns?

Tags: datatables-1.10

I have a DataTables table where I want it to autosize as default (when resizing window and according to initial content etc.), except for one special column, for which I'd like to have a fixed width.

It seems, if I set a width using `columnDefs`, the table is initially autosized according to content, but it no longer adapts to a changed window width. Doesn't seem to matter if I specify a % width or a pixel width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want precise control over the table column widths you *must* use CSS:

```css
table.dataTable thead th:nth-child(4),
table.dataTable tbody td:nth-child(4) {
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

If you inspect the above column you will see the that *computed* `width` is larger than `200px`. This is the padding kicking in, so you must reset `padding-left` and `padding-right` to get exactly 200px.

If you want to shrink a column to a width beyond "reasonable" you must add som additional CSS :

```css
table.dataTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Why this is needed you can read about here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout#Values

```css
table.dataTable thead th:nth-child(2),
table.dataTable tbody td:nth-child(2) {
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  width: 20px;
  max-width: 20px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/n4j1wgu5/**

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. In the meantime, I found a somewhat similar solution, but strangely enough I chose to add CSS using JS after the DataTables initialization, and also have that JS remove the width settings that DataTables adds. Tested now with simple CSS width rules, and it works. Thanks for pointing out the obvious. :-)