# jQuery DataTables column.width option not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using [datatables](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width)

1. as per [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width), it says to use `columns.width` option to control column width
2. when I use `columns.width` and render table, it ignores this width and uses its own width

**JSFIDDLE:**
https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/bvgu0cL3/28/

1. I am using 2 columns with long strings to test if i an apply width to it
2. column **name** has long string without spaces
3. column **description** has long string with spaces
4. I am trying to apply width 200px to **name** column

**Question:**

1. what is the point of this `columns.width` if table will still enforce its own width
2. how can I apply width 200px to **name** column and see it in action ?

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    'autoWidth': false,
    'scrollX': 'true',
    'scrollY': 300,
    'scrollCollapse': true,
    columns: [{
      data: 'name',
      title: 'Long Name Issues',
      width:'200px',     
      render: function(data) {
        return  '<span class="">'+ data + '</span>';
      }
    }, {
      data: 'position',
      title: 'Position'
    }, {
      data: 'description',
      title: 'Long Description Issues',
      width:450,
      render: function(data) {
        return data;
      }
    }, {
      data: 'salary',
      title: 'salary May have Big Title'
    }, {
      data: 'age',
      title: 'age'
    }],
    data: [{
      name: 'DavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavidDavid',
      position: 'CTO',
      description: 'CTO',
      salary: '1000',
      age: '44'
    }, {
      name: 'John',
      position: 'tech',
      description: 'description',
      salary: '1000',
      age: '22'
    }, {
      name: 'Amber',
      position: 'CEO',
      description: 'SOME long description with spaces SOME long description with spaces',
      salary: '1000',
      age: '45'
    }],
  });

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The width property is merely useful for overall relative widths. In your case you also have a `word-wrap` issue. Define a CSS class and apply it to the column:

```css
.px200 {
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```js
columns: [{
  data: 'name',
  title: 'Long Name Issues',
  className: 'px200', //<----
  render: function(data) {
    return  '<span class="">'+ data + '</span>';
  }
}
```

updated fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/bvgu0cL3/30/**

Since you are wrapping the content into a `<span>` you might consider adding a class to that `<span>` instead of the `<th>` and `<td>`'s which `className` does.

If you want total control over the widths, see this answer -> [jQuery DataTables fixed size for ONE of the columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47674920/1407478)

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. As it seems witdth option is useless.

Comment: However in my case , I want widths to applied by user preference. User wants to define a column width. In this case , i cant use ```className``` , so i was thinking perhaps I could use ```createdRow``` and for given width I could apply css to td with   ```{  width: 200px;  max-width: 200px;  word-wrap: break-word;}```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/bvgu0cL3/39/show
i added min-width: 200px; to class and applied class to all columns.
with bigger screen , table violates max-width:200 px
can you please explain for this behavior

Comment: @django, DT also tend to set a calculated width on the entire table, based on the container width.  To control the overall width set the *_wrapper width, i.e `#example_wrapper { width: 800px; }` or similar https://jsfiddle.net/bvgu0cL3/48/show/.  Also notice you are using bootstrap, that injects classes like `col-sm-12` etc, so the table is actually designed to fit the entire container. But yes, tables is in general somehow annoying, not just DT, does not behave like all the other block elements. And I agree, `autoWidth` and `columns.width` in DT is more or less useless.

Answer (score 4):

Based on answer from [@davidkonrad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48326214/2139859)
Here is alternate approach.

**UPDATE:**
I created a plugin which applies defined css in columns
[dataTables.colStyle.js](https://gist.github.com/mafar/c74d5a966119a926db9f5e1fe57f8c82)

**usage:**

```
// init
$('#example').DataTable({
  columnStyle: true // init plugin
});
// use in columns like this
columns: [{
  data: 'name',
  title: 'Name',
  css: {
    'width': 200,
    'min-width': 200,
    'word-wrap': 'break-word',
    'max-width': 200,
  }
}]
```

**Pros:**

1. It uses `column.width` option and applies `css` instead of `classes`
2. No need to define ```classes
3. uses `createdRow` callback to do automation
4. Column titles are always in one line , meaning they will not stretch in height if table width is too small
5. Minimum width of column is always what is required to keep column titles in one line. If you provide width of `50px` to a column , it will still stretch so that title is in one line even if it has to exceed given width of `50px`

working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/bvgu0cL3/42/

**More suggestions are required to make it more elegant**

**CSS:**

```
/* keep the damn titles in one line*/
.dataTable thead td,
.dataTable thead th {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

**JS:**

```
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
     "createdRow": function(row, data, index) {
      var tableApi = this.api();
      var columns = tableApi.settings().init().columns;    
      var tds = $(row).find('td');
      tds.each(function(index) {
        var $td = $(this);
        var columnIndex = tableApi.column(this).index();
        //var columnIndex = tableApi.cell(this).index().column; 
        var hasWidth = columns[columnIndex].width;
        if (hasWidth) {
          $td.css({
            'width': hasWidth,
            'max-width': hasWidth,
            'min-width': hasWidth,//will enforce fixed width, skip if not required
            'word-wrap': 'break-word'
          });
        }
      });
    },
  });
```