# How to set the width of an individual column?

Tags: angular, datatables, datatables-1.10, angular-datatables

I am using [Angular DataTables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started) to display some data stored in a database. There is one column called `description` which can contain a lot of text and ideally it would have a bigger width than the remaining columns:

[image]

I tried using [`columnDefs`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width) as well as [`autoWidth`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth) but without success (I tried both individually as well as a combination of the two). In my `component.ts` file:

```
  dtOptions = {
    pagingType: 'full_numbers',
    pageLength: 5,
    scrollX: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    columnDefs: [{width: '40%', targets: 5}]
  };
```

And then in the component.html

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let column of feedbackTable.columns">
          {{ column }}
        </th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of feedbackTable.data">
      <td *ngFor="let cell of row">
        {{cell}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The `scrollX` works fine, however, I don't get the column width changed. Am I using `dtOptions` correctly?

When I incorporate the answer from below, it still does not effect the column's width:

```
<th *ngFor="let column of feedbackTable.columns" [class.description]="column === 'user_description'">
```

and

```
 th.description {
    width: 40% !important;
  }
```

still give

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem that Angular Data table have an option to set the column width through `dtOptions` but you can achieve this with CSS

Comment: @mkhayata: Could you elaborate on this? Would you add this in the `ngFor` part?

Comment: I have posted an answer

Comment: You need to use CSS if you want exact control. See [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48320337/1407478) and [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47674920/1407478) answer ...

Comment: @davidkonrad thanks for the links! Currently traveling, so I can test it only in a few days.

Answer (score 2):

I tried every combination of datatables options and CSS from this and other posts, nothing worked.

You need to update the column's style AFTER datatables has rendered it. There might be a callback I could hook into from the datatable to trigger the action, but I just set a quick timeout and it worked fine. In my ngOnInit:

```
    setTimeout(()=>{
      let firstColumn = document.querySelector('th');
      firstColumn.setAttribute('style', 'width: 150px !important;');
    }, 10)
```

You may need to do this again if the table is re-rendered later.

Comment: Would have to find the code again; have not looked into this again for almost a year. It looks good though, so I gave it an upvote for now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with CSS as follow:

Add a CSS rule

```
th.description {
  width: 40%;
}
```

Then in your component template, you can apply the description class only to the description column with Angular class binding:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let column of feedbackTable.columns" [class.description]="column === 'description'">
      {{ column }}
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

It will also be better to you make the condition based on the ID of the column instead of the displayed name but then you need to augment your column property to be an object e.g. `column={id: 'desc', name: 'description'}`

**Update with ngStyle:**

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let column of feedbackTable.columns" [ngStyle]="{'width':column === 'description' ? '100px' : '' }">
      {{ column }}
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it does not seem to have any effect; when I inspect the element it still shows an arbitrary width. I will play a bit more and then - if it works - upvote and accept...

Comment: Data table might be setting the width with another CSS class with higher priority than your `description` class. Try to update your CSS rule `width: 40% !important`  and if this works then for a better practice remove `!important` and enhance your CSS rule to get a higher priority than the one provided by Data table.

Comment: Also the `!important` does not help; will investigate.

Comment: OK, you can post the inspection from the devtool to see what could be the issue.

Comment: I edited my question and added a screenshot. Would highly appreciate if you could take a look, thanks!

Comment: The reason is that the Data table is injecting the `style` attribute which contains the width that overrides any CSS rule. Try to use `ngStyle` I update the answer to show how.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but still no luck; output looks the same as before. But well, this answer should help me to dig deeper, so I upvote for now and accept, if I find a solution. Thanks for your help!